# Squares and constants in the dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have 
$$
\begin{eqnarray} 
x'&=& x^2 - y^2 -1 \\ 
y'&=& 2y 
\end{eqnarray}
$$ 
How can I solve such a system? I have tried the substitution $X= x^2 - 1$ but I still get constants in the new system as well as square roots this time. I need some advice on the proper substitution to use so as to solve the system. Thank you very much.

Comment: **Hint**: $$\frac{dy}{dt}=2y\rightarrow ln(y)=2t+c\rightarrow y=Ae^{2t}$$ means
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2-(Ae^{2t})^2-1$$ Then try looking up  how to tackle the second part at http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SystemsDE.aspx

Comment: @JackPedley, That´s the whole lot of hurdles that I was having before!!!!!!. I got to that point please but all seems not to get me any where.

Comment: @KaRJXEN Could you add those steps to your question such that we can see where you encounter problems?

Comment: @fibonatic I meant obtaining $y = k e^{2t}$ but then you still have $x´ = x^2 - (k e^{2t})^2 - 1$.

Comment: @KaRJXEN Are you familiar with [separation of variables](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables)?

Comment: @fibonatic, yes I have used separation of variables before

Comment: I do not get it: one user refers the OP to a page dealing with *linear* differential systems (this one is not), another to a page dealing with separable systems (how is this system *separable*?). Where all this is going to?

Comment: If [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%27%3Dx%5E2-y%5E2-1%2Cy%27%3D2y) is right, the solutions can be simplified to $$x(t)=1-ae^{2t}\frac{\cosh(s)+b\sinh(s)}{\sinh(s)+b\cosh(s)}\qquad y(t)=ae^{2t}$$ for $s=\tfrac12ae^{2t}$ and some parameters $(a,b)$. The ratio can still be simplified, using addition formulas for $\tanh$.

Comment: @KaRJXEN separation of variables isn't applicable here, since there is no product of a function of only $x$ and a function of only $t$. I initially thought it way for some reason.

Comment: To fully solve this, note that the solution $y$ is clear so we can concentrate on $x$, to which we apply the change of variable $$x(t)=1-y(t)z\left(\tfrac12y(t)\right).$$ Lengthy but standard computations then yield that $$z'(u)=1-z^2(u),$$ from where it should be clear that $$z(u)=\frac{ce^{2u}-1}{ce^{2u}+1},$$ for some constant $c$ (a formula equivalent to the first one we gave above).